# About javascript runtime behavior and interval

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, setinterval

When there's an interval method running the background, can it cause the current function to stop in the middle, go do the interval method and then return to the current function?

For example:

```
setInterval(bar, 1000);

function foo(){
    a();
    b();
    c();
}

foo();
```

Is it possible that when reaching `b()` for example to go and do `bar` or `bar` will execute only after the current function (`foo`) is done?

PS: I'm asking about how it will work on Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The interval is added to the events loop (queue) and new item from this event queue is only picked up when the call stack is empty. This means that the `foo` should finish executing before new item is processed from the queue. Moreover, it's not only functions added through interval won't get executed until `foo` is finished, it's all other things like UI events and network request callbacks.

[Here is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) a good talk that explains what this queue is.

Comment: So basically every function call in js is blocking.

Comment: it depends on what you mean by 'blocking'? what do you compare it to, threads?

Comment: A blocking function doesn't let anything else happens until it finishes, like some input functions in C or C++ for example.

Comment: @kuhaku, yeah, they are blocking in this sense.